# How to make a jQuery Toggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_toggle

the thing here is that i change the button to an transparent image.
and i want the image to change when the the `<div>` is hidden.

for example:
The image is a arrow pointing down (when i click the arrow i want the image to disappear)
and i want a new image pointing up to show the `<div>`.

If you dont understand i have a image here:
[image]
 that's what is happening now; you see that even when my div is hidden it show the "hide div button".

In the image below you can see what i want!
I want the image to chane when the  is hidden to "show div".

Remenber that the image is .png

[image]

Comment: I think you need to see [lipsum](http://lipsum.lipsum.com/).

Comment: The link you provided has nothing to do with the images you supply.  Perhaps you need to create a http://jsfiddle.net instead of modifying the example at http://www.w3schools.com so you can share what you've changed with us.

Comment: @Dominicanstan I suspect what he's saying is that Lorem Ipsum text works better as an example than a bunch of repeated characters.

Comment: @tvanfosson Thanks! i will do that in my next questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use an toogle from one of the effects like fade and slide.

Like this:

```
$('#me').click(function() {
    var f = $('#pan').is(':hidden') ? 'show' : 'hide';
    if (f == 'hide') {
        $('#pan').slideUp();
        $(this).html('Show ▼');
    }
    if (f == 'show') {
        $('#pan').slideDown();
        $(this).html('Hide ▲');
    }
});
```

See [how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/t2pLe/1/)

I personally don't like the toggle function, so I kind of just make my own.
I know you want to use an image, but you can still do this with a little change in the code.

Comment: I just don't like it. I'll rather make my own.

Answer (score 1):

I'm editing the example code of w3cschool website.

see below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
    if($("p").css('display')=='none')
    {
      $(this).html('Show!!');
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).html('Hide!!');
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Hide!!</button>
<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To save on some code, you could use this:

```
$("button").toggle(function(){
   $("div").show();
   $(this).html("Hide div.");
}, function(){
   $("div").hide();
   $(this).html("Show div.");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/W8zj7/).